# iOS UIImage returns null after downloading from NSURL

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

I have a loop that cycles through an array of urls which then saves images from those urls. This all works fine until the last image which returns a null image. I have verified that the url is correct and shows the image when i visit it in a web browser. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here.

Here is the loop:

```
-(void) downloadImages {
NSString *filePath;

NSLog(@"About to start loop");
for (int i = 0; i < urls.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Downloading: %@", [names objectAtIndex:i]);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [urls objectAtIndex:i]]]]];

    filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/images/%@.png", [[MakeAMemeIAPHelper sharedHelper] getDocumentsFolder], [names objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"Saving: %@", [names objectAtIndex:i]);

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    progress += 0.1;
    [self updateProgress];
}
NSLog(@"Done with loop");
}
```

Comment: Is it systematically the last URL? If you loop for example from 0 to 5 instead of from 0 to urls.count, does it return null for the last index (4) ? Also which part returns null, the UIImage initWithData?

Comment: I second that question. Have you tried putting a file manager into the loop and confirmed that there is a file at the end of the URL using fileExistsAtPath:?

Comment: Another suggestion: why not just get the NSData from the URL and save that - why go through the trouble of converting the NSData to a UIImage, and then converting that to a PNG, and then saving that as NSData?  Doing so only makes sense if you are downloading other image formats (such as JPEG) and want to also be converting them to PNG - otherwise, it's a lot more efficient just to write the URL contents directly to disk.

Comment: the reason i do urls.count is that the array of urls is not always the same number. However i will experiment with that when i am able and see if that gives me the correct result. Also Rob thats a good idea, i will try that.

Comment: Also I believe it is better to use **NSTimer repeat:YES** here. Looping on **for** loop takes much less time than saving a file on disk. Hope helps...

Comment: I fixed it. turns out the last url was the wrong file format